# Slim Framework Route parameter and realtive resource paths

Tags: url-routing, relative-path, slim

I'm working with Slim and its routes parameter in relative-path web application.
When I'm using html views, I should change the resource relative paths according the route. For example:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/books/:one/:two', function ($one, $two) {
    $app->render("image.html");
});
```

with this view:

```
<html>
<body>
  <img src="./relativepath/img.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously the image could not be found by client than I should change path to:

```
<img src="../../relativepath/img.jpg" />
```

My question is: **is there any way in Slim to do this automatically?** Exists any buildin for this?

I thought to use a variable to get the deepness of route, and then calculate the path prepend string. For example reading how many "/" there is in the request url... but Slim has also wildcards, so it can be difficult to get the deepness:

```
$app->get('/hello/:name+', function ($name) {
    // Do something
});
```

Mind that unfortunately I cannot use absolute paths for resouces.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found:

```
$urlfolder=substr_count($app->request->getResourceUri(), '/')-1;
$urlprepend="";
if($urlfolder>0){
    for($i=0;$i<$urlfolder;$i++) $urlprepend.="../";
    $app->config('urlprepend',$urlprepend);
}
```

Than I use the variable `$urlprepend` or `$app->config("urlprepend")` in every relative path in html view.